# Problems with using VS Code and miniconda for python notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda, miniconda

I have a conda base environment that I want to use for a python notebook. In this base environment I've installed all the packages that I need. However, when I launch a jupyter notebook through vscode, it always gives me a ModuleNotFound error:

[image: vscode]

I've made sure that my python interpreter (bottom left) is conda base as well as the interpreter in the top right:
[image]

but the error never goes away.

The weird thing is that when I launch jupyter lab from terminal in my conda base environment, everything works fine as expected. What could be causing this error?

Comment: View the upper right corner, Is Jupyter also connected to `Python3.8.6 64bit('base':conda)`? If not, click and choose the interpreter which current terminal is using, then run the code again.

Comment: I've tried that to no avail.

Comment: Does these code work well in python file when run it in integrated Terminal?

Comment: Yes when I activate base env in terminal and run "python test.py" for a test file it correctly imports sympy.

Comment: Should I just make a conda virtual environment and use that? Is it bad practice to use conda's base environment? I'm just using numpy and sympy to do some calc3/diffeq stuff so I thought I would just use the base environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled miniconda3 and installed anaconda instead. It magically fixed the problem. I love coding.